# Remove the log shipping configuration on the secondary server, when the primary is no longer available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, log-shipping

My primary server with SQL Server 2005 broke down, so I've started up the log-shipped database on the secondary server. The database is live on the secondary server, and I just need to remove the log shipping settings for it, while the primary server is no longer accessible.

It seems that the `sp_delete_log_shipping_secondary_database` stored procedure should be executed on the secondary server to do this, which "removes a secondary database and removes the local history and remote history", as it is stated on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188928.aspx).

Would this also remove the database itself? Or only the log shipping settings for it? And what will it do when the primary server is not accessible?

I must not loose the database on the secondary server, as it is already in use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are facing what is called orphaned entries in logshipping tables in msdb. You can use below tsql to just **manually** clean up logshipping orphan entries. For your case, since you don't have the primary database available, you should just run the `secondary` part **or** you can try running `sp_delete_log_shipping_secondary_database N'secondary_database'`. It will just remove the secondary database settings from msdb.

```
----- on primary
delete from [dbo].[log_shipping_monitor_primary]
where primary_database = 'your database name'       -- Change the database name 
go
delete from [dbo].[log_shipping_primary_databases]
where primary_database = 'your database name'        -- Change the database name
go
delete from [dbo].[log_shipping_primary_secondaries]
where secondary_database = 'your database name'      -- Change the database name


----- on Secondary
delete from [dbo].[log_shipping_monitor_secondary]
where secondary_database  = 'your database name'     -- Change the database name
go
delete from [dbo].[log_shipping_secondary]
where primary_database = 'your database name'        -- Change the database name
go
delete from [dbo].[log_shipping_secondary_databases]
where secondary_database = 'your database name'      -- Change the database name
```

Note: Above methods are safe and will delete ONLY logshipping related information.