# Clearing Log Shipping config Secondary server inaccessible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping

We are using SQL 2012

Our Secondary server in a log shipping configuration went offline never to come back (the VM was permanently deleted before log shipping configuration was updated).

On the Primary server, I am trying to clean up the LS configuration but everything I've tried times out and/or gives me errors about having configuration still existing.

I have done the following:

- Deleted the LS jobs from the primary server (Backup and Alert)
- Run the Stored Procedure "sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary" with success
- Attempted to run the Stored Procedure "sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_database", this fails.

The error with `sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_database` is as follows:

> Msg 32011, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_database, Line 51
>   Primary Database <"DB name"> has active log shipping secondary database(s). Drop the secondary database(s) first.

If I try to use the SQL management studio GUI, it tries to get me to log into the Secondary server (no longer exists) and times out/errors when it cannot communicate with it.

How do I get log shipping configuration cleaned up on the Primary server, knowing that the Secondary one doesn't exist anymore?

I have flexibility to do a backup/restore of the database during troubleshooting, if needed.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by cleaning up the msdb database, from the linked/duplicate question "primary database" code: 
[duplicate question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119388/remove-the-log-shipping-configuration-on-the-secondary-server-when-the-primary)

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error few months ago and solved by this.

```
USE master;
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary
    @primary_database = N'<PrimaryDatabase>'
   ,@secondary_server = N'<SecondaryServer>'
   ,@secondary_database = N'<SecondaryDatabase>'

GO
```

Comment: I have already tried that. - bullet #2 in my original question

I get errors when I try executing sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_database but I can run sp_delete_log_shipping_primary_secondary with success